How to find active InputField, isFocused does not work
I am trying to find the active InputField.
In the code I create InputFields and add them to the list, in the list they are added, but I can't get them in isFocused. The main task is to compare the data entered by the user and the data in the Placeholder of the InputField.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LetterManager : Loader<LetterManager>
{
    public static LetterManager instance = null;

    [SerializeField] private string word;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite wordSprite;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject buttonLetter;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject letterUIPanel;
    [SerializeField] public string inputText;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI buttonText;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField _inputField;

    private List<TMP_InputField> inputFieldsList = new List<TMP_InputField>(); 
    

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            GameObject newButtonLetter = Instantiate(buttonLetter, letterUIPanel.transform) as GameObject;
            newButtonLetter.name = $"Button{i}";
            buttonText = newButtonLetter.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            buttonText.text = word[i].ToString();
            _inputField = newButtonLetter.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
            inputFieldsList.Add(_inputField);
            Debug.Log(buttonText.text);
            
        }
        foreach (var input in inputFieldsList) //here check list InputField is OK
        {
            Debug.Log(input);
        }
    }

    public void LogInputText() //assigned to event manager in InputField, NOT work!
    {
        foreach (var input in inputFieldsList)
        {
            if(input.isFocused) Debug.Log(input.name);
        }
    }
}



It probably only works for your last input field looking at your code.  You need a local variable instance to add to the list, not a class level, otherwise you're adding the same variable say 20 times, but it will only point to the current contents of the class level variable

@BugFinder a list is not a Linq capture space ... whether you use a local variable or class field (a class field just logically doesn't make much sense) - you always add a different reference to the list so the list itself should be fine actually (also just confirmed this in the editor ;) )

OP why exactly do you go through the TextMeshProUGUI? If you wanted to set an initial value for the input field you should rather go through _inputField.text = ... in general have you confirmed (log or breakpoints) that the LogInputText is called at all? And are you sure that in the moment it is called the input field is actually still active (e.g. if you hit submit or cancel the input it might already have lost focus when the event is raised)

Otherwise I just tried and isFocused works as expected - again of course only given the case that the input field actually is focused in that moment. Instead you could go by the selected state and rather check for if (input.isFocused || EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == input.gameObject) Debug.Log(input.name);

@derHugo In debug mode I found out the problem is that the execution is not even included in the foreach body, in the LogInputText method the collection for some reason turns out to be empty. Why?

@Grimuar typically that would indicate that this is called on a different instance than the one where you logged Start ... for instance a prefab that isn't actually part of the scene ... put a Debug.Log($"LetterManager {this}", this); in the Start method .. how many times does it log? And also put it into the LogInputText method .. click on the message and the according object will be highlighted in the project view / hierarchy ... is it the expected object?

@derHugo Indeed, in the body Awake refers to the instance on the scene and in LogInputText it refers to the Prefab. This indicates that my Singleton is not working correctly.

@Grimuar I don't see where you would ever assign instance or what your base class Loader does exactly ...

Solved the problem, it was necessary to explicitly indicate on which instance we are calling Foreach.
foreach (var input in LetterManager.Instance.inputFieldsList)

But the isFocused method still doesn't work, you need to search using
EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject == input.gameObject

